# ServiceStack JWT Auth Provider example

Tags: servicestack, jwt

Can anyone get me ServiceStack's JWT Auth Provider example.

I want to use servicestack for user registration and login.

Also google, facebook, twitter for sign up.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the docs on [JWT Auth Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) which provides both Server registration and Client examples.

[techstacks.io](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks/blob/71ac5ecd91d35e9181b6debb944294a51eba514e/src/TechStacks/TechStacks/AppHost.cs#L63) and [gistlyn.com](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Gistlyn/blob/7f7525ea9883f25c17f5d77d1cfe6ec3ce74d56c/src/Gistlyn.ServiceInterface/AppData.cs#L137) are some examples that uses both OAuth and JWT Auth Providers.